Comparing different version's values within same column - Power BI
My data set looks like this in PBI. Run_Type (Versions) in picture below goes up to 3, but in reality there's going to be many more different run_types (Versions).
enter image description here
I am looking to select any two different run_types in the two independent slicers I have created and be able to easily compare the KPIs between the two run_types, as well as having a column for % difference. So
I am really stuck. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
So, the desired matrix would look something like this. I want to ensure also that Run_Type A is always before Run_Type B in the matrix.
enter image description here

What is the definition of run type A and B

Run type A And Run type B are just the two selected run types i want to compare. A should be before B and % diff should be based on (B-A)

This can be achieved by following method.
First thing need to consider is how to create the row header for each KPI (distance, volume etc.) for this the dataset need to be unpivot. See below example, I have only considered Distance and Total cost as an example.

Once you're done that, load that as a table and create a duplicate table with run types as below.

The relationship between these two should look like below, with and inactive relationship connected by Run Type

Now for filters, Type A should come from Table and Type B should come from the Run_type table
There will be 3 measures as below
Measure 1
Run type A = 
VAR selectedval =
    CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Run Type ] ) )
VAR selectedval2 =
    CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Run_type'[Run Type ] ) )
VAR distance =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ), 'Table'[Run Type ] = selectedval )
RETURN
    IF ( selectedval <= selectedval2, distance, BLANK () )

Measure 2
Run type B = 
VAR selectedval =
    CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Run Type ] ) )
VAR selectedval2 =
    CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Run_type'[Run Type ] ) )
VAR distance =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ), 'Table'[Run Type ] = selectedval2 )
RETURN
    IF ( selectedval <= selectedval2, distance, BLANK () )

Measure 3
Difference = [Run type B] - [Run type A]

Now create a Matrix with the following as fields.

Download the PBIX file from here.
Don't forget to accept and upvote.

Thank you!  I will give this a try and let you know how it goes!

Hi It's working, check the PBIX file in the answer. Let me know how it goes.

Hi, it works! My issue now is the following...there a lot of different KPIs I need in the matrix as well such as $/load, Km/Volume, $/Volume. How do i create this measures now, and how can incorporate them into the matrix visual? As well, I wanted to put some of these KPIs into line graphs by month but it's not working properly

Glad that it worked, will you please be able to accept the answer and upvote?
Add other columns as before and unpivote those. Measure and the matrix will take care the rest.
